# Is it possible to update a local JSON file when updating a webpage only using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, save

I have made a table using JS, HTML and CSS and I've populated that table with info from a local JSON file. I want to make it such that when I remove a row from the table and then click 'submit/save' the page 'remembers' this and then removes the deleted rows information from my local JSON file. I have looked around the internet for something like this but can't seem to find anything on how to update a local JSON file through interacting with a webpage. I know how to do this using local storage but want to see how it can be done with local JSON file.

If its not possible to update a local JSON file, is it possible when I remove the row(s) and then refresh the page, that the page 'remembers' which rows were deleted somehow so it displays the new table with the appropriately removed rows by using JavaScript?

I am not sure the topic names I should be googling to make this work. I have all the functionality apart from the 'save' part.

Any help would be appreciated to get me started. Thanks.

Tried googling this for a good while today but don't think there is anything on this at least I haven't seen anything that related to my problem. So currently, I just have a normal table being populated by my local JSON file and can remove rows. But I can't make it 'remember' which rows have been deleted, either by updating the local JSON file (is this is possible) or just making the page remember that I deleted a row from the table so when I refresh it comes back with the appropriate table.

Comment: use `localStorage.myTable = JSON.stringify(table)` to save and `table = JSON.parse(localStorage.myTable)` to load

Comment: You can use the [File System API](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#concepts) to update local files.

Comment: Yes, @Barmar, but the status of that API is very much "in development". Here's the [current browser support](https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api) for it.